# Can i use workflow 2013 to update the friendly URL term to match the updated wiki page name

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, remote-event-receiver, workflow2013

I usually work with sharepoint on-premises 2013, and when i work with enterprise wiki site collection, i write the following server side event receiver, which mainly update the friendly URL term to match the updated wiki page name. as by defualt if i create a new wiki page named "**test 123**", then its friendly url will be "**test-123**". but if i modify the wiki page name for example to be equal to "**test 123 updated name**".. then this new name will not be reflected inside the friendly url term. so when i am inside on-premises i write the following ItemUpdated event receiver, to update the friendly url to match the new wiki page name :-

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
//code goes here
// main code is
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
                        {
                            string currenweburl = properties.RelativeWebUrl;
                            using (SPWeb spCurrentSite = site.OpenWeb(currenweburl))
                            {

                                Term currenttermset = null;
                                TaxonomySession txSession = new TaxonomySession(site);
                                TermStore tc = txSession.TermStores[termstorename.Trim()];
                                Group g = tc.Groups[groupname.Trim()];
                                TermSet ts = g.TermSets[termsetname.Trim()];
                                foreach (Term t56 in ts.Terms)
                                {
                                    string targetPageURL = "";
                                    if (t56.LocalCustomProperties.Keys.Contains("_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl"))
                                    {
                                        targetPageURL = t56.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl"];//.Replace("%5B", "[");
                                    }
                                    // string targetPageURL = t56.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl"];//.Replace("%5B", "[");
                                    //  targetPageURL = targetPageURL.Replace("%5D", "]");
                                    if (targetPageURL.ToString().ToLower().Trim().Contains(properties.ListItem.Name.ToLower().Trim()))
                                    {
                                        currenttermset = t56;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (currenttermset != null && currenttermset.Id != null)
                                {
                                    string modifieddisplayname = properties.ListItem.DisplayName.Replace(";", "");// since the ; is the only charecters which is allowed inside the Name but not insdie the term. so if the name contain ; an eror will be raised when i try to add the term
                                    modifieddisplayname = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(modifieddisplayname, @"\s+", " ");//i did so since if the name contain two white spaces or more it will be added as single white space inside the term
                                    string modifeidtemr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(currenttermset.Name, @"\s+", " ");
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString())
                                        && (modifeidtemr.Trim() != modifieddisplayname.Trim()))
                                    {
                                        string modifieddisplayname2 = properties.ListItem.DisplayName.Replace(";", "");
                                        currenttermset.Name = modifieddisplayname2;

                                        tc.CommitAll();
                                        SPListItem newlogentry = xlogs.AddItem();
                                        newlogentry["Title"] = "Term= " + modifieddisplayname2;
                                        newlogentry.Update();



                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

in short the above event receiver will do the following main operations:-

1. loop through the related navigation term.
2. get the term which have its target page = the updated wiki page.
3. check if the term equal to the wiki page name. (i have to replace ; with empty space) since i can have ; inside the name while this character will be automatically removed from the term name.
4. now if the page name is not equal to the term name. i will updated the term accordingly..

now i know that inside office 365 world i can not write server-side event receivers, and at this stage i am afraid i do not have the required knowledge and experience to write the above as remote event receiver. so my question is whether i can use workflow 2013 to be able to update the friendly url term to match the new wiki page name??
Thanks

Comment: Another option can be using powershell script which will check it periodically and fix it using CSOM.

Comment: @PetrŠtěpka looks promising ... but can you post sample code ? please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the HTTP request activity and using the REST api to do this task ?

I use it to update lists sometimes when working with workflows built in SharePoint Designer.

The specifics on how to update list items or library items can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

I don't know if event receivers run in a sandbox solution, I just know that running in sandbox mode you cannot make a HTTP call.

You could create a workflow that takes a parameter and updates the appropriate field using that and the instructions found [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) on how to configure a HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

The managed navigation feature in SharePoint Server enables you to build navigation for a publishing site that is derived from a SharePoint Server managed metadata taxonomy.

In SharePoint Server 2010, by default, you could base navigation only on the structure of a site. To create site navigation based on any data structure, you had to create a custom navigation provider.

By using managed navigation, you can design site navigation around important business concepts. Managed navigation also lets you [login into your router easily](https://routerlogin.one/192-168-100-1/) and  create friendly URLs without changing the structure of your site.

In SharePoint Server 2010, all publishing site URLs contained a reference to the Pages library and any folders within that library.

For example:
http://contoso.com/Pages/AboutUs.aspx.

In SharePoint Server 2016 and SharePoint Server 2013, you can create URLs that are better for Search Engine Optimization (SEO), and easier for site visitors to read.

For example:

http://contoso.com/AboutUs.

Managed navigation is not available in SharePoint Foundation 2013.